# How to sync pdf highlights between iphone and linux?

Tags: pdf, sync, iphone

Currently, I'm using Okular for highlighting PDFs, but it doesn't have a feature for syncing between different devices. I tried to download adobe and it seems that the only available version is the old one that doesn't have that feature either(I tried wine but it was too complicated so I gave up). So how can I sync pdf highlights between ios and ubuntu?
My Ubuntu version is 20.04.4